Combine Multilines in one element of array
I have part of switch config include all interface ethernet port configuration.
Interface Ethernet1/0/12
 switchport mode hybrid
 switchport hybrid allowed vlan 21-29 untag
 switchport hybrid native vlan 21
 mac-authentication-bypass enable
 mac-authentication-bypass guest-vlan 21
Interface Ethernet1/0/13
 switchport mode hybrid
 switchport hybrid allowed vlan 21-29 untag
 switchport hybrid native vlan 21
 mac-authentication-bypass enable
 mac-authentication-bypass guest-vlan 21
Interface Ethernet1/0/14
 switchport mode hybrid
 switchport hybrid allowed vlan 21-29 untag
 switchport hybrid native vlan 21
 mac-authentication-bypass enable
 mac-authentication-bypass guest-vlan 21
Interface Ethernet1/0/15
 switchport mode hybrid
 switchport hybrid allowed vlan 21-29 untag
 switchport hybrid native vlan 21
 mac-authentication-bypass enable
 mac-authentication-bypass guest-vlan 21

I need to convert each block like this:
Interface Ethernet1/0/12
 switchport mode hybrid
 switchport hybrid allowed vlan 21-29 untag
 switchport hybrid native vlan 21
 mac-authentication-bypass enable
 mac-authentication-bypass guest-vlan 21

into element of array.
The count rows below "Interface Ethernet1/0/12" can be difference
Can you show me example how can do it?


The simplest solution is to use -split, the string splitting operator with a regex that splits at each newline (\r?\n) that is followed by a non-whitespace character (\S):
$arrayWithBlocksOfLines = 
  (Get-Content -Raw file.txt) -split '\r?\n(?=\S|$)' -ne ''

Tip of the hat to Mathias R. Jessen for suggesting that the regex consume the newlines between blocks, so that they don't become part of the array elements.

The above assumes a file as input; if the text to process is in a variable in memory, replace (Get-Content ...) with a reference to that variable.

For an explanation of the regex and the option to experiment with it, see this regex101.com page, but in short:

\r?\n is a cross-platform pattern for matching a single newline.
(?=…) is a positive lookahead assertion that looks for a pattern without capturing it as part of a match; that pattern is \S, a non-whitespace character or (|) $, the end of the input string (the latter ensures that a trailing newline at the end of the input is consumed too).


Finally, -ne '' filters out the empty array element that results from the splitting regex matching at the end of the input if it has a trailing newline.



Nice, although I'd consider consuming the linebreak: (?m)\r?\n^(?!\s)

Good idea, @Mathias, thanks, but that still potentially leaves a trailing newline to remove; I went with -split '\r?\n(?=\S|$)' -ne '' in my update.
